# How change URL and don't reload page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-history, html5mode

**My AngularJS project uses `html5mode`, I do these codes to open html5mode**

- In HTML:

```
...
<base href="/features-A/">
...
```

- In JS:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5mode(true)
}])
```

***NOTE***: the `/features-A/` is not an actual folder in my project, it is just a behavior defined in AWS CloudFront, Because we also have some URL `/features-B` point to other projects, We only need to know that: Whether it is accessed via "http://myhost.com" or "http://myhost.com/features-A/" is the entry file for my project: `index.html`

**Here is what the browser does**:

1. when going to my "Sign In" page, The URL in the address bar is

   `http://myhost.com/features-A/signin`
2. When going to **"Home"** page, The URL in the address bar is

   `http://myhost.com/features-A/ome`

As we see, AngularJS changed the URL via `History` API add `/features-A/` inside to the URL

**What I want**

1. when people access "Sign In", The URL does not have `/features-A/`:

   `http://myhost.com/signin`
2. When people access the "Home" page, The URL has `/example`:

   `http://myhost.com/features-A/home`

This will make our website looks like the Sign In page is a system that is independent and outside `/features-A/`.

**What I tried**

I have tried some solutions however they haven't worked:

1. Set base href Dynamically In `stateChangeSuccess` event but URL still changed
2. Use HTML5 history API `pushState` and `replaceState` function, this way would cause page refresh indefinitely

So, Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Change `base` tag to `/` and then define your routes accordingly.

Comment: @varunagarwal `/example/` is defined in HTML and added by AngularJs Automatically

Comment: If you change your base tag to / it should work.

Comment: @Rey Wang If it's possible please share code regarding this, So that we can check this issue in better way

Comment: @ReyWang go to `index.html` and look for a `<base>` tag. Change that from `/example/` to `/`

Comment: @Ajinkya I added some information to make my question more detailed.

Comment: @varunagarwal I updated my question to be more detailed

Comment: Okay, change your AWS setup to render `feature-B` first when pointing to `/features-B` else attempt to serve the application in `feature-A` and in the `index.html` of feature-A, change the base tag to `<base href="/">`

Answer (score 0):

how do not you create a new virtual host?

via php

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

type this Command in your folder's project

Comment: My problem is the `/example/` is added by AngularJS Automatically, I think its not a problem about `router`

Comment: My project is on AWS S3, so this way may be not work